# Calling a Google Form through the Custom Menu of Google Spreadsheet created by the script editor and open it through a pop/modal

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I want to create a Custom Menu on Google Sheets through the Script Editor that creates a pop up or modal from an HTML file that shows the Google Forms linked in the HTML file. So far this is what I have.

```
function onOpen() {
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Records")
  .addItem("Dump","menuItem1")
  .addItem("New Patient Record", "menuItem2")
  .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi ()
     .alert('You clicked the first menu item!');
    }

function menuItem2() {

 var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
     .setWidth(250)
     .setHeight(80)

 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Form');
}
```

as for my html file which is name form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSexWWi3ru1bzwDVhG1TU0hqAeS6VCi-6LDju8KqG7zZv1tBxg/viewform' method='get' id='foo'></form>
    <script>document.getElementById('foo').submit();</script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the pop/modal I have for now and it does not call the google form link
[modalinsheetspicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpT1V.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your form.html file, insert your form inside an iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/123/viewform" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```